# TypeScript without casting

Tags: typescript, casting

I've been coding TypeScript for a few years now. I've seen it evolve and improve so much with every release. Still, all this static typing perfection falls apart with casts.

Despite coding in TypeScript so much, I still don't understand how to **avoid casting** in functions that generate object transformations.

Like in the following example: I want to take an object as input, and return a transformed copy of this object as output.

```ts
function stringifyProperties<T>(obj: T): { [P in keyof T]: string } {
    let stringified: { [P in keyof T]: string } = {} as any;

    for (let k in obj)
        stringified[k] = JSON.stringify(obj[k]);

    return stringified;
}
```

That `as any` cast really breaks the spell, but I can't find a way to avoid it. Is it even possible?

Thanks!

Comment: You can go with `let stringified = {} as { [P in keyof T]: string };` instead of `any`. But I suspect you'd like to avoid the type assertion at all

Comment: Yes, to me, that too feels like cheating.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In TypeScript the real problem isn't casting by it self but specifically the `any` type which looses all type information and static checking. To avoid using `any`-casts for accumulators you may mark these as being a `Partial` application of your structure and when you're sure these are complete cast it to the full object without "any" intermediary typeless state.

In your case I would have used the following solution:

```
type StringifiedProps<T> = { [P in keyof T]: string; };
function stringifyProperties<T>(obj: T): StringifiedProps<T> {
    const stringified: Partial<StringifiedProps<T>> = {};

    for (const k of Object.keys(obj) as Array<keyof T>) {
        stringified[k] = JSON.stringify(obj[k]);
    }

    return stringified as StringifiedProps<T>;
}
```

Comment: @Fabio Iotti, How is this different from `const stringified = {} as StringifiedProps<T>`?

Comment: [@AlekseyL.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1113002/aleksey-l) `{} as StringifiedProps<T>` shuts up the compiler, telling it that `{}` is a `StringifiedProps<T>` (which is not true), while `{} as Partial<StringifiedProps<T>>` tells it that it is an object optionally with the properties in `StringifiedProps<T>` (which is true). Following [@Fenton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/75525/fenton)'s explanation, this seems to be the most elegant solution because typing is always correct.

Comment: @FabioIotti but at the end you're doing exactly the same thing: `stringified as StringifiedProps<T>` to  shut up the compiler. If you'll skip one of the keys assignments the code will still compile, but the result will be wrong

Comment: [@Aleksey L.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1113002/aleksey-l) I partially agree: I don't like casts as they might silently break the code. That's why I asked the question in the first place, but if the answer is «there is no way to write the code in a completely safe way, but if you do it this way you won't be cheating», I'll settle for it.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe any spell has been broken. TypeScript is optionally typed, and you want to perform an operation within your function that is dynamic - so the `any` type allows that dynamic behaviour.

The three lines of code where you create an empty object with no properties (which cannot possibly satisfy the type you have supplied), and the subsequent loop where you add each of the properties to this new object _ought_to be dynamic statements, which the `any` type is there for.

The only way to avoid this would be to write a single line of code that could be resolved into the correct type.

I always like to make the code as honest as possible, so I would probably state explicitly that `stringified` requires dynamic behaviour.

```
function stringifyProperties<T>(obj: T): { [P in keyof T]: string } {
    let stringified: any = {}

    for (let k in obj)
        stringified[k] = JSON.stringify(obj[k]);

    return stringified;
}
```

That way, you only promise the correct type on the final line, not before (i.e. you don't say it is `{ [P in keyof T]: string }` until it is `{ [P in keyof T]: string }`, which is *after* you add all of the required properties.

The result to callers is the same:

```
const objA = {
    A: 1,
    B: 2,
    C: 3
}

//const x: { A: string; B: string; C: string; }
const x = stringifyProperties(objA);
```

Comment: «I always like to make the code as honest as possible, so I would probably state explicitly that stringified requires dynamic behaviour.» I did not think this way before. From now on, this is going to be my thinking when I code in TypeScript.

However, as suggested by [Tim Lundqvist](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7128051/tim-lundqvist), declaring as `Partial<{ [P in keyof T]: string; }>` and then casting to `{ [P in keyof T]: string; }` feels a little more secure to me. After all, using `any` kills any form of type safety.

Answer (score 1):

The reason it falls apart is because you're initializing the variable with your special "stringify" type as an empty object. Casting the empty object to `any` merely suppresses the error.

Take for instance this simple interface:

```
interface Foo {
    bar: string;
    baz?: string;
}
```

In order to assign to a variable declared with type `Foo` the assignment must meet the requirements of the interface.

```
let foo: Foo;
foo = {bar:'fizz'}; // No error.
foo = {baz: 'buzz'}; // Error, bar must be defined.
```

Since your "stringify" type says that every property from `T` exists in the new object typescript complains because you're assigning an empty object to a type with required properties.

The only way to avoid casting would be to declare your "stringify" type as having optional properties for every property in `T`.

```
let stringified: { [P in keyof T]?: string } = {};
```

This means you would also need declare your return type the same way.

If you choose to keep the cast, you could instead perform the cast as you return, and declare the variable as `any` up front since you are building the object rather than declaring it all at once as would be required. This is more of a personal preference, but I think it's more readable and accurately describes what is really going on.

```
let stringified: any  = {};
...
return stringified as { [P in keyof T]: string };
```

Comment: «If you choose to keep the cast, you could instead perform the cast as you return […]» I agree, this feels more elegant than casting to a wrong type though `any`. Still, declaring as `{ [P in keyof T]?: string }` as you proposed feels even better to me. Thanks.